# Проблема с LinkedList добавляется лишний пробел при Assert.assertEquals()

Tags: java, linked-list, equals

Есть своя реализация LinkedList, пытаюсь ее протестировать с помощью junit, но получаю error из-за того что добавляется лишний пробел:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected :impl.LinkedListOwnImpl<B; A; >*в этом месте пробел* 
Actual :impl.LinkedListOwnImpl<B; A; >
```

У меня была такая же проблема со своей реализацией ArrayList, проблема была в том что я забыл переопределить equals.
Но в LinkedList и внутреннем классе Node методы equals переопределены. Вроде все правильно. Я чего-то не замечаю? В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class LinkedListOwnImpl<T> implements LinkedListOwn<T> {


    private Node<T> firstNode;
    private Node<T> lastNode;
    private int size;

    public LinkedListOwnImpl() {
        lastNode = new Node<>(null, firstNode, null);
        firstNode = new Node<>(null, null, lastNode);
    }

    @Override
    public void addFirst(T element) {
        Node<T> newNext = firstNode;
        newNext.value = element;
        firstNode = new Node<>(null, null, newNext);
        newNext.prev = firstNode;
        while (getNextNode(newNext) != lastNode) {
            newNext = getNextNode(newNext);
        }
        lastNode.prev = newNext;
        size++;
    }



    @Override
    public void addLast(T element) {
        Node<T> newPrev = lastNode;
        newPrev.value = element;
        lastNode = new Node<>(null, newPrev, null);
        newPrev.next = lastNode;
        size++;
    }

   private Node<T> getNextNode(Node<T> element) {
        return element.next;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof LinkedListOwnImpl)) return false;
        LinkedListOwnImpl<?> that = (LinkedListOwnImpl<?>) o;
        return size == that.size &&
                Objects.equals(firstNode, that.firstNode) &&
                Objects.equals(lastNode, that.lastNode);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(firstNode, lastNode, size);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        Node<T> node = firstNode;
        while (getNextNode(node) != lastNode) {
            str += getNextNode(node).value.toString() + "; ";
            node = getNextNode(node);
        }
        return str;
    }

    private static class Node<T> {
        private T value;
        private Node<T> prev;
        private Node<T> next;

        Node(T value, Node<T> prev, Node<T> next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Node)) return false;
            Node<?> node = (Node<?>) o;
            return Objects.equals(value, node.value) &&
                    Objects.equals(prev, node.prev) &&
                    Objects.equals(next, node.next);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(value, prev, next);
        }
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

public class LinkedListOwnImplTest {

    LinkedListOwn<String> linkedListOwn;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        linkedListOwn = new LinkedListOwnImpl<>();
        linkedListOwn.addLast("A");
    }

    @Test
    public void addFirst() {
        LinkedListOwn<String> expected = new LinkedListOwnImpl<>();
        expected.addLast("B");
        expected.addLast("A");

        linkedListOwn.addFirst("B");

        Assert.assertEquals(expected, linkedListOwn);
    }
```

Comment: Покажите `getNextNode()` и `addLast()` чтобы нам легче было воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: @Олексій обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема вовсе не в лишнем пробеле, ведь в юнит-тесте сравниваются вовсе не строковые представления объектов.

Чтобы сравнить 2 списка, вам нужно пройтись от начала до конца одновременно по обоим спискам и сравнить значения элементов. Текущий ваш алгоритм рекурсивный и приводит к переполнению стека.

Я чуток исправил ваш код (учтите, я не профессионал Java, поэтому тут могут оставаться ошибки):

```
public class LinkedListOwnImpl<T> implements LinkedListOwn<T> {
    private Node<T> firstNode;
    private Node<T> lastNode;
    private int size;

    public LinkedListOwnImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public void addFirst(T element) {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(element, null, firstNode);
        if (firstNode != null) {
            firstNode.prev = newNode;
        }
        if (lastNode == null) {
            lastNode = newNode;
        }
        firstNode = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public void addLast(T element) {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(element, lastNode, null);
        if (lastNode != null) {
            lastNode.next = newNode;
        }
        if (firstNode == null) {
            firstNode = newNode;
        }
        lastNode = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof LinkedListOwnImpl)) return false;
        LinkedListOwnImpl<?> that = (LinkedListOwnImpl<?>) o;
        if( size != that.size) {
            return false;
        }

        Node<T> node = firstNode;
        Node<?> nodeThat = that.firstNode;

        while (node != null) {
            if (!Objects.equals(node, nodeThat)) {
               return false;
            }
            node = node.next;
            nodeThat = nodeThat.next;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(firstNode, lastNode, size);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Node<T> node = firstNode;
        while (node != null) {
            builder.append(node.value.toString());
            builder.append("; ");
            node = node.next;
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public Node<T> getNextNode(Node<T> node) {
        return node.next;
    }

    private static class Node<T> {
        private T value;
        private Node<T> prev;
        private Node<T> next;

        Node(T value, Node<T> prev, Node<T> next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Node)) return false;
            Node<?> node = (Node<?>) o;
            return Objects.equals(value, node.value);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает